# Good OOP design to avoid copy/paste in Fortran

Tags: oop, fortran, fortran2003

Given the minimal working example below, I would like to modify it to avoid copy/pasting the calls of

```
call func_some_calc1(par)
call func_some_calc2(par)
```

in both `main_func_problem1` and `main_func_problem2`.
Ideally I want to have one function `main_func` that is behaving differently for input parameters of type `t_parameters_problem1` and `t_parameters_problem2`. I could declare its `par` parameter of base type `class(t_parameters_base)`, but then having a switch inside that function depending on the actual argument type (using `select type`) is architecturally not good.

To solve this I tried to create a `procedure` in type `t_parameters_base`, which is calling those routines, to implement something like this (C++ syntax):

```
class t_parameters_base {
  virtual void main_func() {
    func_some_calc1(this)
    func_some_calc2(this)
  }
}
class t_parameters_problem1: public t_parameters_base {
  virtual void main_func() {
    t_parameters_base::main_func();
    func_some_calc3_problem1(this);
  }
}
```

But the problem is that those routines are using an input parameter of this type, which leads to circular dependency. How is it possible to solve this problem?

Update: Note that I really want to keep the implementation of `func_some_calc1` and `func_some_calc2` in different files (modulus/classes) as they implement very different logic using some private functions from their classes.

```
module parameters_base
  type, public :: t_parameters_base
    integer :: n
  end type t_parameters_base
end module parameters_base

module parameters_problem1
  use parameters_base
  implicit none

  type, extends(t_parameters_base), public :: t_parameters_problem1
    integer :: p1
  end type t_parameters_problem1
end module parameters_problem1

module parameters_problem2
  use parameters_base
  implicit none

  type, extends(t_parameters_base), public :: t_parameters_problem2
    integer :: p2
  end type t_parameters_problem2
end module parameters_problem2

module some_calc1
  use parameters_base
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine func_some_calc1(par)
    class(t_parameters_base) :: par
  end subroutine func_some_calc1
end module some_calc1

module some_calc2
  use parameters_base
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine func_some_calc2(par)
    class(t_parameters_base) :: par
  end subroutine func_some_calc2
end module some_calc2

module some_calc3_problem1
  use parameters_problem1
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine func_some_calc3_problem1(par)
    type(t_parameters_problem1) :: par
    print*, par%p1
  end subroutine func_some_calc3_problem1
end module some_calc3_problem1

module some_calc3_problem2
  use parameters_problem2
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine func_some_calc3_problem2(par)
    type(t_parameters_problem2) :: par
    print*, par%p2
  end subroutine func_some_calc3_problem2
end module some_calc3_problem2

module main_problem1
  use parameters_problem1
  use some_calc1
  use some_calc2
  use some_calc3_problem1
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine main_func_problem1(par)
    type(t_parameters_problem1) :: par

    call func_some_calc1(par)
    call func_some_calc2(par)
    call func_some_calc3_problem1(par)
  end subroutine main_func_problem1
end module main_problem1

module main_problem2
  use parameters_problem2
  use some_calc1
  use some_calc2
  use some_calc3_problem2
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine main_func_problem2(par)
    type(t_parameters_problem2) :: par

    call func_some_calc1(par)
    call func_some_calc2(par)
    call func_some_calc3_problem2(par)
  end subroutine main_func_problem2
end module main_problem2

program module_test
  use parameters_problem1
  use parameters_problem2
  use main_problem1
  use main_problem2

  implicit none

  type(t_parameters_problem1) :: par1
  type(t_parameters_problem2) :: par2

  par1%p1 = 1
  par2%p2 = 2

  call main_func_problem1(par1)
  call main_func_problem2(par2)
end program module_test
```

Comment: Why don't you create one routine with a switch. I suggest that instead of using generic `func_some_calc1, ...`, you give short specific names, so everything will be more comprehensible.

Comment: What exactly switch do you mean? If you mean to declare an argument of base type and then convert it inside the subroutine to the inherited type actually passed, using "select type", then it is not a good architecture.

Comment: How about using `t_parameters` and pass the additional one separately for now.

Comment: Yes I could add another function main_func_common, which is taking a variable par of t_parameters_base and is calling the common block, if you mean that. But then putting that function in a separate module looks not a good OOP style to me.

Comment: You pass it through as a second argument. Assuming you do not have many additional arguments, it will be ok. I rather have a base type and other arguments passed separately.

Comment: No there are many extra parameters (about 10 for now, and can be even more).

Comment: If the additional arguments are mutually exclusive, you can create two specific types for them. I am scrutinising your problem and have not got a solution just yet, although a simplification as suggested might turn out to be more beneficial.

Comment: You are requesting a run-time switch between procedures, depending on the actual type of some object.  This can be done only by two constructs, either a SELECT TYPE clause, or by binding the procedure to the object type.

Comment: The latter solution would imply that you bind the `func_some_calc` procedures to the (abstract) base type `t_parameters_base`, in form of a deferred procedure with abstract interface.  This should do the job, but it sort-of implies that the subroutines are secondary to the parameter object.

Comment: You have two basic options. Select type inside, or design everything as type-bound procedures of the given type.

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you are aiming for are polymorphic types with type bound procedures. Below you find a working example. To keep it simple, I do not have added any data to the types, but of course, that can be easily done. The routine `invokeCalc12` is only defined in the base type, but can be invoked from the derived types, and as in Fortran all methods are virtual, it will call the right methods.

```
module calc_base
  implicit none

  type, abstract :: CalcBase
  contains
    procedure(calcInterface), deferred :: calc1
    procedure(calcInterface), deferred :: calc2
    procedure :: invokeCalc12
  end type CalcBase

  interface
    subroutine calcInterface(self, ii)
      import :: CalcBase
      class(CalcBase), intent(inout) :: self
      integer, intent(in) :: ii
    end subroutine calcInterface
  end interface

contains

  subroutine invokeCalc12(self, ii)
    class(CalcBase), intent(inout) :: self
    integer, intent(in) :: ii
    call self%calc1(ii)
    call self%calc2(ii)
  end subroutine invokeCalc12

end module calc_base


module some_calc
  use calc_base
  implicit none

  type, extends(CalcBase) :: SomeCalc
  contains
    procedure :: calc1
    procedure :: calc2
    procedure :: calc3
  end type SomeCalc

contains

  subroutine calc1(self, ii)
    class(SomeCalc), intent(inout) :: self
    integer, intent(in) :: ii
    print *, "SomeCalc1:calc1", ii
  end subroutine calc1

  subroutine calc2(self, ii)
    class(SomeCalc), intent(inout) :: self
    integer, intent(in) :: ii
    print *, "SomeCalc1:calc2", ii
  end subroutine calc2

  subroutine calc3(self, ii)
    class(SomeCalc), intent(inout) :: self
    integer, intent(in) :: ii
    call self%%invokeCalc12(ii)
  end subroutine calc3

end module some_calc


program test
  use some_calc
  implicit none

  type(SomeCalc) :: mySimulation

  call mySimulation%calc3(42)

end program test
```

Note: I've seen that similar question has been posted at [comp.lang.fortran](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/Toj7jN26ThI), but at the moment I did not find a working example there, therefore the posting here.

Comment: Hi Balint, thank you for your answer, I am looking at it. Just wanted to say that I never posted my question at comp.lang.fortran, and am very surprised why someone would actually need to do this...

Comment: @Vitaliy Not sure either, why it appeared there. Anyway, I hope, the example above can help you to get the right solution. :-)

Comment: Hi Balint, in your example you moved the implementation of calc1() and calc2() to the extended class, while those functions are using only base class parameter, and are behaving the same for problem1 and problem2. So it looks to me like you answered a different question. Besides I wanted to keep implementation of calc1() and calc2() in different files (modulus/classes) as they implement very different logic using some private functions from their classes, although I did not mention did explicitly in my question -- I will add this.